# verify value in a Cell A exist in Cell B in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I want to verify that value in cell A is present in Cell B. I used

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$2,1)),"No","Yes") 'this working partially.
```

It is displaying No for the below cell values

> ### Cell A Value:
>
> Walk of Fame
>
> ### Cell B Value:
>
> While We're Young (2015)
>   Critics Consensus: Poignant and piercingly honest, While We're Young finds writer-director Noah Baumbach delivering some of his funniest lines through some of his most relatable characters. ... Noah Boaumbach's comedy While We're Young stars Ben Stiller and Naomi Watts as Josh and ...

what is wrong with this?

Comment: `=IFERROR(IF(FIND(B2,A2),"YES"),"NO")

Comment: Note that FIND is case-sensitive. If you don't want that, use SEARCH instead.

Comment: Is it just me, or does `A` value not show up inside `B` value at all? Which would mean that the output OP describes is correct?

Comment: @Vegard, I'm assuming that the `...` at the end means there is actually more text. Based on the text that is actually shown in the question, the output is correct though. On a sidenote, this looks like a formula in a cell rather than actual VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

```
=IF(A2="","",IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(A2,$B$2:$B$2,1)>0,"Yes"),"No"))
```

The first `IF` checks for an empty search field, and the output field is empty if that is the case. The `SEARCH` looks for the position of the search string in a text. If it is found, it returns the start position but gives an error if the search string is not found. Therefore I surrounded it by an `IFERROR` to return a `No` if the text is not found.

Answer (score 1):

If case doesn't matter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(A2,$B$2:$B$2,1)),"No","Yes")
```

If case matters:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2,$B$2:$B$2,1)),"No","Yes")
```